# Can one element of a cyclic group produce all elements of it if its order is infinity?

Tags: group-theory

Proposition 6 Section 2.3 of the book Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote states:

> Let $H = \langle x \rangle$. Assume $|x| = \infty$. Then $H = \langle x^a \rangle$ if and only if $a = ±1$.

$1-$ How can $H = \langle x \rangle$ if $|x| = \infty$? In other words, is it more (or only way) correct to say $H = \langle x, x^{-1} \rangle$? Because despite the case of finite order in cyclic group in which $x^b=x^{-1}$ for some $b$, there is no $c$ such that $x^c=x^{-1}$ if $|x| = \infty$. And by $x^{-1}$ we mean inverse of $x$ in the group under consideration.

$2-$ Following the question $1$, so does $a = ±1$ in the last word of the Proposition mean $a = +1$ **and** $a = -1$? That is $H = \langle x, x^{-1} \rangle$?

Comment: The group generated by $x$ includes the inverse of $x$, by definition. (Otherwise it wouldn't be a group!)

Comment: Remember that $\mathbb{Z},+$ is cyclic with generator $1$. Which is the definition of group generated by an element?

Comment: @TonyK Yes but for some $b$, $x^b=x^{-1}$ so $x$ is enough to produce $x^{-1}$ also. But this is not true if order is infinity. (?)

Comment: I think that for most people, $\langle x\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup containing $x$.

Comment: @TonyK Unless, $ \langle x \rangle$ is defined to be all **negative and** positive powers of $x$ - not just positive ones.

Comment: It's just part of the definition: you include the inverses. See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group generated by some elements is the smallest group that contains these elements. This implies $x^{-1}\in \langle x\rangle$, otherwise it would not be a group.

For your second question, this means $a=1$ **or** $a=-1$ as either one implies that both must be elements of the generated group.

Comment: I thought that $ \langle x \rangle$ is defined to be all $x^b$'s for $b$ positive and it **implies** $x^{-b}$'s also, because for some $c$, $x^c=x^{-1}$ so $x$ is enough to produce $x^{-1}$ also. So **negative and** positive powers of $x$ all must exist - not just positive ones.

Comment: Thats correct, You usually encounter 2 definitions, one stating exactly what you say, positive and negative powers, and the other one is the one I use most: The smallest group containing the elements. These definitions are equivalent. (easy to prove)

Comment: @Liebe Note that if you were working in a semigroup rather than a group, then it would make sense for $\langle x \rangle$ to only include positive powers.  This makes the "smallest ___ containing $x$" a cleaner definition to carry with you conceptually than one that relies on the specifics of the ambient algebraic structure.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the fucntion $f: (\mathbb Z, +) \to (H, \cdot )$ given by $f(a) = x^a$ is an isomorphism. Indeed

$$f(a_1 + a_2) = x^{a_1+a_2} = x^{a_1}\cdot x^{a_2} = f(a_1)\cdot f(a_2) , \forall a_1, a_2 \in \mathbb Z$$

then $f$ is a homomorphism, I'll let you show that $f$ is a bijection.

Now the element $x^a$ generates $H$, iff, $a$ generates $\mathbb Z$ (since $f$ is an isomorphism), thus $a= \pm 1$.

Answer (score 0):

1) By definition
$\langle x\rangle=\{x^n\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$.

2) What says is that $H=\langle x\rangle=\langle x^{-1}\rangle$, but
$H\neq\langle x^k\rangle$ for every $k\neq\pm1$.